Dmart product page is not fully loading when i am using headless browser in aws lambda
this how i am using it:
def driver_initialize(self):
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        # options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
        options.add_argument('--single-process')
        options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080')
        options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        options.add_argument('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:118.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0')
        
        chrome_binary = '/opt/headless-chromium'
        chromedriver_path = '/opt/chromedriver'
        options.binary_location = chrome_binary

        service = Service(chromedriver_path)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
        return driver

and this is the page that i am trying to open:
driver.get(r'https://www.dmart.in/product/thums-up-multi-pack-bot-psftdrinks0thum13xx70121?selectedProd=824503')
            WebDriverWait(driver, 180).until(
                lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
                
            try:
                WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="text-label-component_title__Qk1fy"]'))
                )
            except:
                print("product page is not loaded")
                
            screenshot_path = '/tmp/screenshot_prodcuts_page.png'
            # time.sleep(180)
            driver.save_screenshot('/tmp/screenshot_prodcuts_page.png')  # Save screenshot for debugging
            s3.upload_file('/tmp/screenshot_prodcuts_page.png', output_bucket, 'screenshot_prodcuts_page.png')
            print(driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;"))

i want to do scrapping on this page but it is not getting loaded no matter how long i wait for it what might the issue be. I am attaching the screenshot that i am getting no matter how long i wait for it:
